# Cannot pass protocol to function with constrained generic type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift2

If you have a function which has a generic type that is constrained to a protocol you cannot pass a value of the type of the protocol to the function:

```
protocol P {}

extension Int: P {}

func testP<T: P>(value: T) {}

// passing Int
let val = 0
testP(val)

// passing Int as P (protocol)
let valAsP: P = 0
testP(valAsP) // error: cannot invoke 'testP' with an argument list of type '(P)'
```

If I change the protocol to a class (and using inheritance instead) the same function would be executed in both cases.

In addition "The Swift Programming Language" book says that

> The colon in the declaration means “…of type…,”

If this is also true for generic constraints I would argue it is a bug.

So should this be considered a bug? Or is there any case where it is useful to have this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per the spec on the definition of [Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/type-name) section:

> A named type is a type that can be given a particular name when it is defined. Named types include classes, structures, enumerations, and **protocols**.

protocols are a valid, named type.

Also supported by the fact that if you remove the `P` constraint from `testP`, the code compiles.

You can resolve your scenario by changing the signature of testP to

```
func testP(value: P) {}
```

which should work for most scenarios.

Incidentally, your scenario is [possible in C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/ef93d154781d7285ff9a6a54472415d8) where interfaces are similar to protocols in Swift

I have created issue [SR-1324](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1324)